# Do homeomorphic metric spaces have equal minimal cardinality of dense subsets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cardinals

Let $X,Y$ be two homeomorphic topological spaces and let $d(X)$ denote the minimal cardinality of a subset $A \subseteq X$ such that $\bar A=X$, *i.e.*, $A$ is dense in $X$. Then is it true that $d(X)=d(Y)$ when $X,Y$ are homeomorphic? I would appreciate even a proof for metric spaces $X,Y$. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Hints** in case of homeomorphism image of a dense set is dense. And remember homemomorphism means it is a bijective map.